# Django returning chain of 2 different model querysets

Tags: python, django

Here is my view

```
serializer_class = SceneSerializer
permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
def get_queryset(self):
    scene = Scene.objects.filter(user = self.request.user)
    for s in scene:
        test = Scene.objects.get(static_id = s.static_id)
        lights = test.light.all()
        temp = list(chain(scene, lights))
```

Here are my 2 serializers

```
class LightSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model = Light
    fields = '__all__'

class SceneSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Scene
        fields = '__all__'
```

Here is my models

```
class Light(models.Model):
static_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
id = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
company = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=True, null=True)
name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
label = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, related_name='userLights' )
def __str__(self):
    return "{0} - {1}".format(self.user,self.static_id)

class Scene(models.Model):
    static_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    color = RGBColorField()
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, related_name='userScenes' )
    light = models.ManyToManyField(Light)
    def __str__(self):
        return "{0} - {1}".format(self.user,self.static_id)
```

Goal is to return the complete objects of the scene and the lights attached to each scene. the chain is working correctly but when I return the chain I am getting

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide detailed information about your problem. Some examples of inputs and expected outputs are always useful. Please, check [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a question for more details as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can include [reverse relationships in serializers](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#reverse-relations) by adding the reverse relationship to `fields`

```
class SceneSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Scene
        fields = ['light', 'static_id', 'color', 'title', 'user']
```

This will just return a list of ids, to serialize the related objects you can add the related serializer with `many=True`

```
class SceneSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    light = LightSerializer(many=True)
    
    class Meta:
        model = Scene
        fields = ['light', 'static_id', 'color', 'title', 'user']
```

Comment: if '.' in source or source == '*':
TypeError: argument of type 'ellipsis' is not iterable

After making those changes I am now getting this

Comment: @Silentflank15 the ellipsis was there to represent the rest of the field names. I've updated the answer with how it would look with your current fields

Comment: My bad, Im still getting a AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field 'light'
AttributeError: 'Light' object has no attribute 'light'

Comment: Did you copy the fields above into `LightSerializer`?

Comment: I haven't touched the LightSerializer. What needs to be copied into it? I have what you posted above and thats the only change I've made